# Ошибка при удалении двумерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, память, матрицы, динамические-массивы

подскажите пожалуйста: почему при удалении двумерного дин.массива программа выдает ошибку.

```
   float **arr= new float*[count];
   for (int i{};i<2;i++)
      {
     arr[i]=new float[i];
       }

   for (int i{};i<count;i++)
    {
     delete[] arr[i];
    }
     delete[] arr;
```

Comment: А у вас `count` точно равен 2? А если нет - то для какого количества строк вы выделяете память (кстати, странно как-то выделяете - в каждой строке свое количество), и для какого удаляете?

Comment: @Harry у меня матрица размера COUNTx2 , count не всегда равно двум

Comment: @Harry а, получается в цикле for я удаляю столбцы, значит мне в цикле for надо указать i<2?

Comment: См. код в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть столбцов - `COLS`, строк - `ROWS`.

```
float ** arr = new float[ROWS];
for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) arr[i] = new float[COLS];

....

for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) delete[] arr[i];
delete[] arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i{}; i<2; i++) {
  arr[i] = new float[i];
}
```

Судя по всему вы выделяете не матрицу, а "треугольник". Причем у вас первая строка - 0 байт. Вы ничего там не аллоцировали. Я даже не представляю какой эффект это дает при `delete`. Вы получаете какое-то исключение?
К тому же вы не итерируете до `count` а до `2`, выходит, что вы аллоцировали две строчки (одну нулевую), а потом удаляете все `count`